# Python application trying to insert into oracle

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I have a simple tkinter application I built to put in the amount of hours I worked. for some reason I keep getting this error "DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" any help will be greatly appreciated!

here is my SnowTime.py

```
import os 
import sys
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import cx_Oracle 
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import time


def insertBcl():
     connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'password', cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'port', 'sid'))
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(TRANSACTION_ID) FROM LABOR")
     for result in cursor:

         r = reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, (result))

         f = r + 1
     #cursor.close()
     #connection.close()


     hours = e1.get()
     today = datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

     SNOWJ = "SNOWJ"
     I = "I"
     OH = "OH"
     W = "W"
     null = "null"
     zero = 0
     N = "N"
     SNOW = "SNOW"



     add_time =("INSERT INTO TEST " 
                    "(EMPLOYEE_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID, TYPE, INDIRECT_ID, HOURS_WORKED, GOOD_QTY, BAD_QTY, SHIFT_ID, SETUP_COMPLETED, PASS_FAIL, CREATE_DATE, REASON, USER_ID, OPEN_OP)"
                     "VALUES (%(EMPLOYEE_ID)s, %(TRANSACTION_DATE)s, %(TRANSACTION_ID)s, %(TYPE)s, %(INDIRECT_ID)s, %(HOURS_WORKED)s, %(GOOD_QTY)s, %(BAD_QTY)s, %(SHIFT_ID)s, %(SETUP_COMPLETED)s, %(PASS_FAIL)s, %(CREATE_DATE)s, %(REASON)s, %(USER_ID)s, %(OPEN_OP)s)")

     data_time = { 'EMPLOYEE_ID': SNOWJ,
                  'TRANSACTION_DATE': today, 
                  'TRANSACTION_ID': f,
                  'TYPE': I,
                  'INDIRECT_ID': OH,
                  'HOURS_WORKED': hours,
                  'GOOD_QTY': zero,
                  'BAD_QTY': zero,
                  'SHIFT_ID': null,
                  'SETUP_COMPLETED': N,
                  'PASS_FAIL': N,
                  'CREATE_DATE': today,
                  'REASON': null,
                  'USER_ID': SNOW,
                  'OPEN_OP': null,
    }    


     print add_time

     print data_time

     cursor.execute(add_time, data_time)

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()  
    connection.close()
```

here is what add_time looks like when printed

```
 INSERT INTO TEST (EMPLOYEE_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID, TYPE, INDIRECT_ID, HOURS_WORKED, GOOD_QTY, BAD_QTY, SHIFT_ID, SETUP_COMPLETED, PASS_FAIL, CREATE_DATE, REASON, USER_ID, OPEN_OP)VALUES (%(EMPLOYEE_ID)s, %(TRANSACTION_DATE)s, %(TRANSACTION_ID)s, %(TYPE)s, %(INDIRECT_ID)s, %(HOURS_WORKED)s, %(GOOD_QTY)s, %(BAD_QTY)s, %(SHIFT_ID)s, %(SETUP_COMPLETED)s, %(PASS_FAIL)s, %(CREATE_DATE)s, %(REASON)s, %(USER_ID)s, %(OPEN_OP)s)
```

here is what data_time looks like print

```
{'CREATE_DATE': '2015-11-13', 'OPEN_OP': 'null', 'HOURS_WORKED': '4', 'REASON': 'null', 'TRANSACTION_DATE': '2015-11-13', 'INDIRECT_ID': 'OH', 'TRANSACTION_ID': 12816058, 'PASS_FAIL': 'N', 'USER_ID': 'SNOW', 'EMPLOYEE_ID': 'SNOWJ', 'SHIFT_ID': 'null', 'SETUP_COMPLETED': 'N', 'GOOD_QTY': 0, 'BAD_QTY': 0, 'TYPE': 'I'}
```

here is my table structure

```
column_name                     data_type 

EMPLOYEE_ID                     VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)            
TRANSACTION_DATE                DATE               
TRANSACTION_ID                  NUMBER(10,0)          
TYPE                            CHAR(1 BYTE)           
INDIRECT_ID                     VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)              
HOURS_WORKED                    NUMBER(7,2)               
GOOD_QTY                        NUMBER(14,4)           
BAD_QTY                         NUMBER(14,4)        
SHIFT_ID                        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)               
SETUP_COMPLETED                 CHAR(1 BYTE)            
PASS_FAIL                       CHAR(1 BYTE)         
CREATE_DATE                     DATE            
REASON                          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)              
USER_ID                         VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)       
OPEN_OP                         CHAR(1 BYTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle odd things can happen when you use reserved key words.

I see you have a table column called TYPE which is a key word.  You could try the double quote trick like this

```
 INSERT INTO TEST (EMPLOYEE_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID, "TYPE", ... 

%(TYPE)s, %(INDIRECT_ID)s, %(HOURS_WORKED)s, %(GOOD_QTY)s, %(BAD_QTY)s, %(SHIFT_ID)s, %(SETUP_COMPLETED)s, %(PASS_FAIL)s, %(CREATE_DATE)s, %(REASON)s, %(USER_ID)s, %(OPEN_OP)s)
```

If you still get odd errors I suggest renaming the column TYPE to something that is not a key word.

Comment: I get a invalid syntax when I put TYPE in double quotes.     "(EMPLOYEE_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID, "TYPE", INDIRECT_ID, HOURS_WORKED, GOOD_QTY, BAD_QTY, SHIFT_ID, SETUP_COMPLETED, PASS_FAIL, CREATE_DATE, REASON, USER_ID, OPEN_OP)"
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax @kevinsky

Comment: I also renamed type to kind_of and I still receive the same ora error.